# image cache not generating when we edit and save product which is redirected from custom module

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

i have a custom module which redirect to product edit in backend but when we save product image caches are not generating.

When we save product from magento default. image cache is generating but after redirecting and saving product image cache is not generating.
775 is also set to pub/media and var/

is there any permission issue or something i am forgetting to enable.

please suggest why image cache is not generating.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image cache generation is enabled in your Magento configuration. To do this, go to **Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Static Files Settings**, and make sure that the "Sign Static Files" and "Merge JavaScript Files" options are set to "Yes".

Comment: by default image cache are generating but after redirecting to product edit image cache are not generating. is there any permission issue of something i am forgetting to enable

Comment: chmod -R 775 /magento/pub/media/;chmod -R 775 /magento/var

Comment: try this commands.

Comment: 775 is already set to pub/media and var/

Comment: Try this chown -R correctuser:correctgroup media/*